# I want a confirmation print everytime it fill 64 integers. ? how to check if i == 64

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int *buff;
    int j = 0;
    buff = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);

    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        buff[i] = i;
        if (i & 0x7f == 64) {
            j++;
            printf("completed %d part out of total %d parts ints\n", j, 512 / 64);
        }
    }
    printf("filling completed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

but the program control never going into `if` statement inside for loop.
I want to get a print statement every time it fills 64 integers.

Thank you.

Comment: `malloc()`s prototype is in `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: using `&` instead that `%` is totally unnecessary and unreadable. Any normal compiler will optimize the code any way when it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is a simple operator precedence mistake. `==` binds stronger than `&`.
You need to write:

```
if((i&0x7f) == 64)
```

Also note that does maybe not what you want, since it prints when `i` is 64+n*128;

You could simply use:

```
if(i%64 == 0)
```

As pointed out in the comments if you want to print when `64` `ints` were wrote into `buf` you should change the condition to:

```
if(i%64 == 63)
```

since when `i` equals `0` you already wrote one element in.

Comment: you do not want a match when `i` is `0` and the number of ints initialized is `i + 1`, so you want to test for `i` multiple of 64 + 63, hence `if (i % 64 == 63)`

Comment: @chqrlie Oh I see your point, and what you mean by `number of ints handled`.I was just taking his code and corrected it, because it seemed to me that in OPs code the intention was to print when `i` is `n*64`. I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

The test is incorrect. It should be:

```
        if ((i & 0x3f) == 0x3f) {
```

Note however that it would be more readable as

```
        if (i % 64 == 63) {
```

Fixing other small problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int *buff = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);

    if (buff == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (i = j = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        buff[i] = i;
        if (i % 64 == 63) {
            j++;
            printf("completed part %d out of total %d parts ints\n", j, 512 / 64);
        }
    }
    printf("filling completed\n");
    free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more compact version. You don't need `j`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *buff = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);

    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = i;
        if (i % 64 == 63)
        {
            printf("completed %d part out of total %d parts ints\n", (i / 64) + 1, 512 / 64);
        }
    }

    printf("filling completed\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```